# ipywidgets: How to get array input?

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, ipywidgets, matplotlib-widget

I need a widget that takes in an array as input, i.e. something like a hundred sliders (that I don't want to create manually).

How can I achieve this?

I thought the answer would be `widgets.Box`, but then I get the error `Box(...) cannot be transformed to a widget`.

Answer (score 0):

Got it -- the trick is to use `**kwargs`. My code looks something like this.

```py
seed = np.zeros(100)
kwargs = {'seed[{}]'.format(i) : 
          widgets.FloatSlider(
              min = -1.0, 
              max = 1.0, 
              step = 0.01, 
              value = seed[i]) 
          for i in range(100)}

@interact(**kwargs)
def Generate(**kwargs):
  return seed
```

A better solution will nonetheless be appreciated, because I don't know how to change the layout and stuff with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `HBox` or `VBox`, not just `Box` for a container.

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets
from ipywidgets import interact
n = 10
seed = np.zeros(n)
sliders = list(widgets.FloatSlider(
              description = 'seed[{}]'.format(i),
              min = -1.0, 
              max = 1.0, 
              step = 0.01, 
              value = seed[i]) 
          for i in range(n))

widgets.VBox(children = sliders)
```

Comment: No, this is not the problem -- widgets.Box works here too. It is only when one actually puts an interact script with the Box (or VBox) widget that you get the error.